# Google Drive api Java QuickStart EOFException

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, drive

I am following google drive v3 api quickstart 
[tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java)
I don't want to use gradle for this application since is a group project. 
I have downloaded the google drive v3 libraries.

I am using Intellij, and I have added all of the jar to the class path. All jars are imported successfully and the IDE doesn't give any error.

At run time I get a warning which from reading online seems to be a problem with Windows Compatibility.

I have downloaded the .json file with user ID and user secret and placed it in the same folder as the main

My code is the same as the one of the quickstart example:

The error i get is the following:

```html
Apr 06, 2017 2:31:52 PM com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for everybody: C:\Users\HP\.credentials\drive-java-quickstart
Apr 06, 2017 2:31:52 PM com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for owner: C:\Users\HP\.credentials\drive-java-quickstart
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2624)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:3099)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:853)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
 at com.google.api.client.util.IOUtils.deserialize(IOUtils.java:171)
 at com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory$FileDataStore.<init>(FileDataStoreFactory.java:102)
 at com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory.createDataStore(FileDataStoreFactory.java:73)
 at com.google.api.client.util.store.AbstractDataStoreFactory.getDataStore(AbstractDataStoreFactory.java:55)
 at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.StoredCredential.getDefaultDataStore(StoredCredential.java:171)
 at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeFlow$Builder.setDataStoreFactory(AuthorizationCodeFlow.java:736)
 at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow$Builder.setDataStoreFactory(GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.java:209)
 at com.elox.Main.authorize(Main.java:77)
 at com.elox.Main.getDriveService(Main.java:93)
 at com.elox.Main.main(Main.java:103)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

I don't Understand why I get this error or how I could correct it

Comment: Where do you have the user credentials?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old post, but I had almost the exact same stacktrace and couldn't find an answer. So, I'm posting in hopes that it will help those that come after me.

The issue appears to be related to file/directory permissions. As soon as I changed the filepath being used by the FileDataStoreFactory to a directory that my application had read/write permissions to, OAuth2 worked correctly. So, make sure that you are using a non-restricted filepath and that all of the directories have the correct ownership and permissions.